# Buffering selected polygons within same feature class using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: editing, buffer, clip, arcgis-pro

**The limitation below applies only to ArcGIS Pro versions 1.0 - 1.2.**

---

When editing in ArcMap a workflow I used to create a polygon feature with a donut polygon *in the same feature class* around it was to:

1. Digitize the polygon
2. Use the Buffer from the pulldown on the Editor menu to create a buffer polygon larger than the original
3. Select the original polygon and use the Clip from the pulldown on the Editor menu to discard any part of the buffer polygon that fell under it.

Is there an equivalent workflow available in ArcGIS Pro?

From what I have seen the Buffer and Clip Geoprocessing tools are still there under ANALYSIS but these work at the feature class rather than feature level.

@ChrisW pointed out that there is also a [Clip under Modify Features](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/basics/clip-one-or-more-features.htm) that seems equivalent to (and better than) Editor | Clip but it is the Buffer on the Editor menu pulldown that seems to have gone missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested ArcGIS Pro 1.3, and there can now be found the [Buffer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/create-a-buffer.htm) tool that I was looking for:

> In the Modify Features pane, Buffer creates polyline or polygon
>   buffer features around selected features at a specified offset
>   distance. The destination layer is specified by choosing a feature
>   template. When you create buffers around two or more features, you can
>   merge the resulting buffers into one nonoverlapping buffer by
>   selecting Dissolve.